# Phalcon PHP. How should look data for save relation one-to-many?

Tags: php, phalcon

I wanna save relations for Articles and categories.
I have 3 tables & models like this: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#defining-relationships

And I have next code to generate checboxes:

```
<div class="form-group">
{% for category in categories %}
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="{{category.id}}">{{category.title}}</label>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

How need to be looks data for save this data automatically? In "automatically" I mean without foreach for adding ID article manualy.

Data, what I try to save:

```
array (size=5)
  'users_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'title' => string 'Title here' (length=10)
  'content' => string 'content here' (length=12)
  'categories' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '4' (length=1)
      2 => string '5' (length=1)
  'slug' => string 'slug-go-here' (length=12)
```

In my method I try save like this:

```
$post = new Posts();
                $success = $post->save($data);

                $array = array_values($this->request->getPost("categories_id"));

                $categories = Categories::find(
                    array(
                        'id IN ({ids:array})',
                        'bind' => array(
                            'ids' => $array
                        )
                    )
                );

                $post->setPostsCategories($categories); 
                $post->save();
```

Model Posts:

```
public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo("users_id", "Users", "id");
        $this->hasOne("id", "PostsImages", "posts_id", [
            'foreignKey' => [
                'action' => Relation::ACTION_CASCADE
            ]
        ]);
        $this->hasMany("id", "PostsCategories", "posts_id", [
            'foreignKey' => [
                'action' => Relation::ACTION_CASCADE
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

Model Categoroes:

```
public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany("id", "PostsCategories", "categories_id");
    }
```

Model PostsCategories:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->belongsTo("posts_id", "Posts", "id");
    $this->belongsTo("categories_id", "Categories", "id");
}
```

By the way. In phalcon have any tag for adding/displaying multiple checkboxes?

Comment: Show how you get the data (method in your controller), what have you tried?

Comment: Where are your getters, setters and private variables?

Comment: I use magic setters & getters.
I mean i get vars like this: $post->title;

Comment: I understand, you need to add the categories to the model somehow and replace this `$user->setCategories($categories);` with `$user->categories = $categories;` or `$user->Categories = $categories;`. I haven`t worked like this because I like to have things under control :)

Comment: I try this. It not help. Its saving without errors but in db records not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I create a work code :)

```
            $data = $this->request->getPost();

            // New entity of Post
            $post = new Posts();

            // Creating new entities of PostsCategories and setting categories id
            foreach ($data["categories_ids"] as $k => $id) {
                $posts_cats[$k] = new PostsCategories();
                $posts_cats[$k]->categories_id = $id;
            }

            $post->PostsCategories = $posts_cats; // Set array of PostsCategories objects in related to Posts model "PostsCategories"
            $success = $post->save($data); // The save
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do the following at some point in a method in your controller:
Assume you already got your data from the form:

```
//$id retrieved from POST
//$categoriesIds = $_POST['categories'];
```

You need to create the entities, bind them and save them:

```
$user = User::find('id', $id);
$categories = Categories::query->inWhere('id', $categoriesIds);

$user->setCategories($categories); //I`m guessing here
$user->save();// if you defined the relationships correctly this should work
```

Comment: $post = new Posts();
$success = $post->save($data);
$array = array_values($this->request->getPost("categories_id"));
$categories = Categories::find(
        array(
            'id IN ({ids:array})',
            'bind' => array(
                'ids' => $array
            )
        )
    );

$post->setPostsCategories($categories);
$post->save();

But I have error: The method 'setPostsCategories' doesn't exist on model 'Posts'

Comment: Added init func from models.